# File preview broken in Windows 10 Explorer for all documents, only image formats are previewed

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, preview

Is there anything generic that can be done in this case, i.e. if the file preview is broken for all document formats?

Examples: PDF, TXT, DOC, DOCX, RTF, HTML, MHT, XLSX, PPT, INI, MSG, EML etc. all do not work.

Windows Explorer Folder Options:
[image: Folder Options]

Ditto, machine translation
[image: Folder Options translated]

Comment: Have you tried Restore Defaults?  Restore defaults and restart.

Comment: Thanks, will do (although I don't have much hope there)

Comment: I recall seeing this issue going back several years. It's not particularly common, but it has happened for a long time, and I've seen solutions for it before. Have you researched the general internet or this site for similar questions and tried Thr solutions?

Comment: I have tried Restore Defaults in Folder View options, but that didn't help.
Also, I have used literally every method available on the entire internet for decades, and it never has helped (permanently). Now, document file preview seems to be broken for good. So I'd like to completely uninstall all preview handlers and reinstall them one by one.